# Centering a Bootstrap element cross-device compatible

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap

Community,

I recently stumbled upon Twitter Bootstrap while looking for possibilities to design a webpage without being able to actually "design" (coder-cliché, meh). I've gotten a big fan of it's instant cross-compatibility and as the site is planned with a blog in mind I do not consider it impossible that it will be visited by mobile users.

And that specific blog is what causes me problems. Having a blog post span about the whole grid (span12, up to 1170px in width) creates a massive wall of text that would scare everyone away. Instead, I decided to create (atleast the previews) in span6, which seems reasonable to me and also works good for mobile users. But as I don't want more than 1 per row I'll need to center it somehow, and I would prefer to do it "the Bootstrap way".

The official docs pointed me to the .offset* classes, which work great on desktops, but will be preserved when switching to the mobile layout, creating an ugly gap on the left side. Without the offset it works without problems on the mobile version (1 post per row, no gap left or right) but on desktops it is left-aligned. Here the relevant bit of the code:

No offset, working as intended on mobile devices:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <h3>Blog Post #1 Title</h3>
        <h5>Category, Sub-Category - 01.01.1970</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div><!--/span6-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

With offset, working as intended on desktops:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <h3>Blog Post #1 Title</h3>
        <h5>Category, Sub-Category - 01.01.1970</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div><!--/span6-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

Is there any way (without JavaScript!) to get it to behave like I want to (cross-compatible centering of the element while keeping all text in it left-aligned)? I'd guess I'll need to change the bootstrap-responsive.css, but I'd like to restrain from messing with the original files...

Comment: You may have to change the media queries if they're not working as they should. Without scripting it, the other way around may be to change the CSS instead.

Comment: @tahdhaze09 I am interested in this question too. I am trying to do just that, essentially remove the offset class if the screen is small enough. How can I do that? I tried setting margin-left: 0% to offset classes on small screens but it had no effect.

Comment: @mattgmg1990 - no need to remove the class, just don't use it! The best way  to create your page is to start from scratch. I followed the advice of the creators and experimented with the classes, adding some elements a little at a time - "Move beyond the base template with a few example layouts. We encourage folks to iterate on these examples and not simply use them as an end result.". I made a general page that reacts responsively without the offset class.

Comment: @tahdhaze09 Are you advocating not using bootstrap at all when you say "The best way to start your page is to start from scratch." I really just wanted to position several elements in the center of their containers, but only on the desktop screen sizes. On phones, however, I want everything stretching the length of the screen. I understand from your comment that you think that I shouldn't use offsets, but how specifically can I accomplish this without them?

Comment: Sorry, @mattgmg1990! What I meant was to start from a base of bootstrap, withpout all of the bells and whistles. They have a base template that basically has almost nothing in it. You can create your HTML5 template page just by including the basic in the head, like the jQuery and the css files. From there, create your layout, just  don't use the offset class. If you go to their Getting Started page, they have some samples and some base code to work with that should give you a nice start to a responsive web page.

Comment: Oh okay, well that makes sense to me. I realize that I don't have to use all the bells and whistles but I still can't decide what the best way to push an element away from the side without using offsets AND keep it responsive would be besides the answer given below, using a blank span that you hide on the phone screen sizes. In all of the examples, they don't do any spacing like I want to do or like OP wanted to do. Thanks for discussing this with me though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I just got an idea that turned out to be working perfectly fine, without using any CSS modifications:

To center the element using the grid-system we fill the rest of the row with placeholders. For my *span6*-example that would be

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span6">
        <h3>Blog Post #1 Title</h3>
        <h5>Category, Sub-Category - 01.01.1970</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

which results in a centered version on desktop and tablets, and in a full-width version on phones. However, due to the fluid layout, there will be gaps in the mobile layout, as the empty div's also take a small amount of space. But as that problem only occurs on phones, we can avoid it by adding the *hidden-phone*-class to the placeholder-div's, like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3 hidden-phone"></div>
    <div class="span6">
        <h3>Blog Post #1 Title</h3>
        <h5>Category, Sub-Category - 01.01.1970</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 hidden-phone"></div>
</div>
```

And, in the end, that works like I intended it to, atleast on Bootstrap version 2.1.0...